# windows上で作ったrubyスクリプトをrubyコンテナ上で実行したい

Tags: ruby, docker

#### やりたいこと

windows上にdockerでrubyコンテナを作り、windows上で編集したrubyスクリプトを実行する。

#### 試したこと

- 次のとおり定義し、rubyコンテナを作る ( `$ docker-compose up -d` )

```
version: '3'
services:
  rubyapp:
    image: ruby:2.5-alpine
    container_name: myruby
```

- rubyスクリプトをwindows上に用意する (git for Windowsを使用)

```
C:/home/docker/myapp/
|-- docker-compose.yml
`-- ruby
    `-- app
        `-- test.rb


$ echo "puts Time.now" > ruby/app/test.rb
```

#### 結果

次のコマンドを実行

```
# Windows上のパスを指定すると見つからないエラー
$ winpty docker run -v "C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/root ruby:2.5-alpine ruby ruby/app/test.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- ruby/app/test.rb (LoadError)


# コンテナ上のパスを指定してもエラー
$ winpty docker run -v "C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/root ruby:2.5-alpine ruby /root/test.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- C:/Program Files/Git/root/test.rb (LoadError)


# -eオプションでは実行できる
$ winpty docker run -v "C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/root ruby:2.5-alpine ruby -e "puts Time.now"
2018-12-17 05:47:23 +0000
```

コマンドの指定方法が悪いのか、そもそもできないのか、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @kyohah     確認が遅くなって失礼しました。こちらでも再度試して動くようになりました。`$ docker run --rm --volume="C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/sample ruby:2.5-alpine ruby sample/test.rb` これでコンテナ上のトップディレクトリにsampleというフォルダができ、Windows上のmyapp/ruby/appがマウントされた状態になります。

Answer (score 1):

rubyをただ実行したいだけであれば、docker-compose.ymlの作成は不要です。

上記のコマンドだと
workdirが設定されていないためエラーになっているのだとおもいます。

`$ docker run --workdir=/app --volume="C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/app ruby:2.5-alpine ruby test.rb`

また、ファイルが見つからなかったときは
`$ docker run --workdir=/app --volume="C:\home\docker\myapp\ruby\app":/app ruby:2.5-alpine /bin/sh`
でマウントされたファイルを探しに行くのもいいでしょう